# using JAVA Loop

Tags: java, loops, newline

Write an application that counts by five from 5 through 500 inclusive, and
that starts a new line after every multiple of 50 (50, 100, 150, and so on).

How would I move to a new line to print the multiples of 50 ?

```
package loop2;

/**
 *
 * @author whitneykenny
 */
public class Loop2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        
        int i = 5;
        while (i <=500) {
        
        System.out.print(i + " ");
        i = i + 5 ;
        
        }          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats that for a crappy formatted question?

Please format that into a readibilty question.

However, what you need is

```
if (i % 50 == 0) System.out.println();
```

That code will check by modulo-operator if you've reached 50-steps and if so prints a new line

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use a for loop for this question.
Since I assume you are a beginner I've commented everything so its easy to understand.

This was done on mobile so sorry about the formatting.

```
//set your variables
Int maxnum = 500; //the value to count to
Int NewLineAt =50; 

//looks 500 times and starts at 5, adds 5 each loop
For (int i = 5; i <= maxnum; i+=5)
{

//if your number divides into 50 with no remainder add
//a new line with the "/n" which means new line
    If ( i % NewLineAt == 0)
    {
        System.out.print(i + "/n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use System.out.println() instead of System.out.print();

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 5;
        while (number <= 200) {
            System.out.print(number + " ");
            if (number % 50 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            number += 5;
        }
    }
}
```